# Why are localized resources not used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, cultureinfo

I'm working on an existing project and I'm currently facing a weird problem :

In the main web project are stored some resource files in the `App_GlobalResources` folder :

- `Application.fr.resx`
- `Application.resx`
- `Application.designer.cs`

In the code, those resources are accessed this way :

```
global::Resources.Application.Some_Resource
```

This works, and the localized resources are found when set to FR culture.

In another project (referenced by the main web project), the resources are stored in a `Resources` folder :

- `Messages.fr.resx`
- `Messages.resx`
- `Messages.designer.cs`

And they are accessed by calling :

```
My.Project.Namespace.Messages.Some_Other_Resource
```

In this case, the resources are found and used, but the culture is not taken into account and the returned values are always the default ones.

I googled around, but didn't find anything really helpful. I'm not familiar with ASP.NET cultures, so maybe I missed something obvious.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into that issue with some of my projects.
My guess would be that in one of your project you are setting somewhere UICulture, but you do not do it in the other. That could be in your "base" page code or global application code.

Comment: You're right. I finally found that a conditional symbol had been added, which forced the culture to a hardcoded value. Thanks !